# R Macro for 2-1-1 Multilevel Mediation Analysis

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I have a 2 (entropy) x 3 (trials) mixed effect design where the first factor is manipulated between SS and the last one is a within subject variable referring to the number of trials that each participant completes. The entropy (IV) is manipulated in individual level (level 2), whereas mediator and DV are measured in trial level (level 1). Mediator and DV are continuous variables. 
Do you have an R or SPSS macro for this mediation analysis? Or do you have any suggestions about where to look at?

Thanks,
Pia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think (You should be sure here) you have 2-1-1 mediation. The internet is full of resources for SPSS. Start somewhere around here "http://afhayes.com/introduction-to-mediation-moderation-and-conditional-process-analysis.html". However, if you want to use R. There are few options. Each with their own limitations. For starter, you might want to look into Tingley, Dustin, et al, 2014, "Mediation" R package. The problem with this one is you cant do sensitivity analysis for multilevel mediation. The other R package is function developed by Elizabeth Page Gould, called indirectMLM ( http://www.page-gould.com/r/indirectmlm/). She has wonderful resources and worked example. This is very convenient. The best thing about this package is you can, if you want, dissect the between and within subject mediation. The other package is the Bayesian Multilevel Mediation package by (Matti Vuorre & Niall Bolger, 2017), however this only do 1-1-1 mediation. Here you have a lot of graphical options and makes many procedures easy. Since your M and Y are continuous I think this package is suitable also. I hope this helps.